# VBA that alerts user when stock is at 0

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have created a query that removes one part from each record when a button is pressed in a form. But what I want to do is, if one of the parts in the table is already at zero then the button is unable to be pressed.
For example, a user is removing a 'kit' which consists of 6 parts. But the user doesnt realise that one of the parts is already at 0. then when they press the button the other parts decrease by one.
How can i prevent this?

Comment: Get a count of the rows for that specific ID and check if it's above 0. Then you can work with that value

Answer (score 2):

When they select the part/kit you need to query the database to verify the part(s) are available then (un)lock the button accordingly. What event you use to do this would depend on how they are picking the part initially.

Another option is to wrap the queries that update your inventory in a transaction so that you can roll them back if one of the parts is not available (or becomes unavailable during the transaction).

There is not enough information to provide any concrete examples though, just suggestions.

Comment: I have an update query that update the Kit table whenever the button is pressed. The kits are in seperate tables. Its a simple database which allows the user to either remove or add in stock.

Comment: Yes but if a kit is a collection of parts then you need to be testing part availability on all of the parts prior to them hitting the button or it needs to be verified prior to attempting to debit the kit from inventory. Either way when modifying multiple records that all depend on each other it is always best to do it in a transaction so you can roll it back if one update fails.

Comment: In one of my forms I have a text box that has a piece of code that works out how many kits are available by calculating the minimum amount of stock in the table. E.g. if there are 2 MEC003 and 0 MEC002 then I have 0 kits in stock. I tried to use this in VBA with the code but I keep getting error messages

Answer (score 1):

"*a user is removing a 'kit' which consists of 6 parts. But the user doesnt realise that one of the parts is already at 0.*"

I think you should approach this differently.  If any of the required parts for a given kit are unavailable, don't give the user an opportunity to press the command button for that kit.

Apparently somehow you are able to determine that "foo kit" consists of 6 parts, and the identities of those 6 parts.  Use similar logic to enable/disable the command button (set its `.Enabled` property to True or False) based on whether or not all the parts are available for the form's current kit.  Or change the form's record source so that it presents only the kits for which all parts are available, and requery the record source after each set of parts removals.

If other users may be simultaneously updating parts, wrap the form's updates in a transaction, as Omnikrys suggested, so you can roll back an attempted set of updates when a part has become unavailable.

BTW, in a comment you said "*The kits are in seperate tables.*"  At first blush that sounds like a design mistake.  However, if that is actually a sound decision, this task will likely be extra complicated.  :-(

Comment: I tried this in the On click event. But I have a text box in the actual kit form, showing you the available kits. I used this:=DMin("[Current Stock]","ASM-00065 WIP") Then i put this into VBA like this
If "Text31" = 0 Then
cmdbtnmacroasm00065.Enabled = False

End If
But I keep getting an error message saying "type mismatch" How can I fix this?

Comment: Its because of the Unique ID's. If i put them all in one table they will all get mixed up. I am changing an excel spreadsheet into a database for my boss. I cant change the Part codes as they are needed for other companies